# getting bash variable into filename for zip command

Tags: bash, zip

In a bash script, how do I use a variable to create a specifically named zipped file?  For example, I would like to do something like:

```
VERSION_STRING='1.7.3'
zip -r foo.$VERSION_STRING foo
```

Where I ideally end up with a file called `foo.1.7.3.zip`

It seems like I'm having 2 problems:

1. the zip command is treating `$VERSION_STRING` like it's null or empty
2. the `.` after `foo` also seems to be mucking it up

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following works fine here using bash 4.1.5:

```
#!/bin/bash

VERSION_STRING='1.7.3'
echo zip -r foo foo.$VERSION_STRING.zip
```

I've added the `echo` to see the actual command rather than run it. The script prints out

```
zip -r foo foo.1.7.3.zip
```

Comment: thanks, echo-ing out the command showed me that my variable had a space in it, which was messing up the zip creation.

Answer (score 29):

you can use `${VERSION_STRING}` to clearly wrap your variable name

Answer (score 11):

I think you have your zip inputs backwards. For me the following command:

```
zip -r foo.${VERSION_STRING}.zip foo
```

creates a valid zip file.  Your command does not (at least with my version of zip).