# How to remove quotes around each element in bash array created from grep capture

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, grep

In my bash function, I am using grep to capture a matching pattern from a string (selecting the files created), and then storing what is captured in an array. The string is assigned to a variable called `output`

```
installing route
  create app/routes/foo.js
  create app/templates/foo.hbs
updating router
  add route foo
installing route-test
  create tests/unit/routes/foo-test.js
```

after running

```
 files=($(echo "$output" | ggrep -oP 'create\s\K(.+)'))
```

I confirm that I am capturing what I intend to by running `echo ${files[*]}`. Output in the terminal looks as so

```
app/routes/foo.js app/templates/foo.hbs tests/unit/routes/foo-test.js
```

My goal is to pass these files as arguments to an npm script (`npm run lint <list of files>`). However, when I try to plug in my variable to the npm script execution, the file names either print out like

```
"app/routes/foo.js" "app/templates/foo.hbs" "tests/unit/routes/foo-test.js"
```

or

```
"app/routes/foo.js app/templates/foo.hbs tests/unit/routes/foo-test.js"
```

The ultimate goal here is to be able to run

```
npm run lint app/routes/foo.js app/templates/foo.hbs tests/unit/routes/foo-test.js
```

I have tried tons of combinations to interpolate my `file` variable, but nothing seems to work. I feel like I am missing something conceptually or approaching this in the wrong way. I originally was trying this without using an array for `file`, but I was running into the same issue. My first pass is getting this to run in bash. However, I'd prefer to stick with using `grep` or `sed` here though. Anyone have any suggestions?

After reading suggestions I have tried

```
parsedfiles=$(echo "${files[*]}" | sed  -e 's/"//g')
echo $parsedfiles
npm run lint $parsedfiles
```

When `echo $parsedfiles` runs my terminal output looks good `app/routes/foo.js app/templates/foo.hbs tests/unit/routes/foo-test.js`, but on the next line, it still outputs as `npm run "app/routes/foo.js" "app/templates/foo.hbs" "tests/unit/routes/foo-test.js"`

**SOLVED**
The real issue here wasn't about how I was passing the args in. It's an issue with actually running the `npm script`. When passing args to the npm script it automatically puts them in double quotes.

Comment: What is the error that occurs currently when the file paths are passed to npm as individual or one large string?

Comment: Have you tried these approaches? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590034/getting-bash-variable-into-filename-for-zip-command or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703624/bash-interpret-string-variable-as-file-name-path

Comment: This might be a good use case for eval? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065077/eval-command-in-bash-and-its-typical-uses

Comment: Thank you for the links! The issue ended up not being with the bash script, but rather passing arguments to the npm run command that was wrapping the filenames in double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sed to edit the text as below.

```
$ var=`echo "app/routes/foo.js app/templates/foo.hbs tests/unit/routes/foo-test.js" | sed  -e 's/"//g'`

test$ echo $var
app/routes/foo.js app/templates/foo.hbs tests/unit/routes/foo-test.js
```

Now you can use var in npm run lint

```
$ npm run lint $var
```

Comment: It appears to look good when I echo $var, but when I interpolate the variable into the `npm run lint command` files still look like `"app/routes/foo.js" "app/templates/foo.hbs" "tests/unit/routes/foo-test.js"`

Comment: Ended up being an issue with running the npm script with arguments, as this is what was putting it in quotes. To accomplish what I originally described this is a great solution. Thanks for you help!